# Generate webpack sourcemaps with css pre/post processors

Tags: css, source-maps, webpack

Has anyone successfully generated (css) sourcemaps with webpack while using a css preprocessor (less/scss/styl)?

I have tried using chained loaders like this:

webpack.config

```
loaders: [{
    test: /\.less$/,
    loader: "style-loader!css-loader?sourceMap!less-loader?sourceMap"
}]
```

but the sourcemap displays the compiled output from less (and not the source), however it displays the correct filename.

whatever.less

```
@red: red;

.whatever {
  color: @red;
}
```

is mapped to /absolute/path/to/whatever.less, with the following contents

```
.whatever {
  color: #f00;
}
```

whatever happened to @red?